# How to exclude field if getter throw Exception in json?

Tags: java, jackson

I try to serialize POJO via jackson.
POJO class provided below

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomerSerializer.class)
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private String id;
    private String address;
...........................
another setters and getters
...........................
    public String getAddress() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

method getAddress throw any exception, but in this case RuntimeException

JsonSerializer provided below must serialize this class and exclude field, where getter throws exception

```
public class CustomerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Customer> {
    public void serialize(Customer base, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    }
}
```

It's simple example with just a few properties, but in production we have a large hierarchy. In this example I can write serializer as, for example:

```
  jgen.writeStartObject();
  jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.id);
  jgen.writeStringField("itemName", value.itemName);
  jgen.writeNumberField("owner", value.owner.id);
  jgen.writeEndObject();
```

but in prod too much properties. May be, Is it possibly passed all field besides address ?

Comment: I'd say you could either tell Jackosn to ignore the properties that you know will cause exceptions, e.g. via `@JsonIgnore` on the class itself or a mixin, or - since you're writing a custom serializer anyway - just call the getter in a try-catch block and handle the exception accordingly.

Comment: If your goal is to just skip some fields during marshaling and un-marshaling then simply put `JsonIgnoreProperties` and pass in the list of fields you want ignored. That should be clean and precise.